# Sqlite select and delete operation using C API in Swift

Tags: c, swift, sqlite

I've following sqlite code using C api within Swift having a read and a delete operation for review.

For those not familiar with Swift, `defer` will execute after the end of the function.

Since I'm not closing the database connection and keeping it alive, I'm calling `sqlite3_db_cacheflush(database)` to flush out the changes to the disk. [Link](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/db_cacheflush.html)

```
class Database {
           
    internal var database: OpaquePointer! = nil
    
    init(_ database: OpaquePointer) {
        self.database = database
    }

    func deleteById(_ id: Int64) throws -> Int32? {
        let sql = "DELETE FROM user WHERE id = \(id)"
        
        defer {
            sqlite3_db_cacheflush(database)
        }
        
        guard sqlite3_exec(database, sql, nil, nil, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
            throw NSError(domain: String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(database)), code: 1, userInfo: nil)
        }
        
        return sqlite3_changes(database)
    }
    
    func findAllDepartments() throws -> [Department]? {
        var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        let sql = "SELECT id, name FROM department"
        
        guard sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
            throw NSError(domain: String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(database)), code: 1, userInfo: nil)
        }
        
        defer {
            sqlite3_finalize(statement)
            sqlite3_db_cacheflush(database)
        }
        
        var departments: [Department] = []
        while sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW {
            departments.append(Department(id: sqlite3_column_int64(statement, 0), name: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1))))
        }
        
        return departments
    }
}
```

Usage of Database Class

```
do {

   if sqlite3_open_v2(url.path, &database, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX, nil) == SQLITE_OK { // Existing database (Serialized mode)
         let db = Database(database)
         try! db.findAllDepartments()
         try! db.deleteById(4)
    } else { // Error opening database
        print(String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(database)))
    }
catch { let error as NSError {
    print(error.description)
}
```

Comment: Have you considered making more of a wrapper around SQLite? So that you wouldn't really get the spilling over of opening a database where you're using the Database class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify what precisely you were looking for, so a few general observations:

1. **You do not need `sqlite3_db_cacheflush`.** When you perform SQL updates, they are written to disk immediately (unless you are using transactions). You can do your inserts, updates, and deletes, leave the database open, and you’ll be fine.
2. **Use `Error`, not `NSError`.** I would advise against `NSError` (unless you needed Objective-C backward compatibility). In Swift, we would define our own `Error` type:

   ```swift
   enum DatabaseError: Error {
       case sqlError(Int32, String)
   }
   ```

   And then

   ```swift
   guard sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
       throw DatabaseError.sqlError(sqlite3_errcode(database), String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(database)))
   }
   ```

   Then, when catching errors, the codes and the error messages are more easily retrieved.
3. **Failure of `sqlite3_open_v2` will leak.** When handling `sqlite3_open_v2` failure, make sure to close the database or else resources allocated to it will never get freed. I know that this seems unintuitive, but the documentation is clear (emphasis added):

   > *Whether or not* an error occurs when it is opened, resources associated with the [database connection](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/sqlite3.html) handle should be released by passing it to [`sqlite3_close()`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/close.html) when it is no longer required.
4. **Method names.** You have a method called `deleteById(_:)`, which does not make it clear what you are deleting. Besides the use of a preposition and parameter name in the method name is common in Objective-C, but not Swift. I would suggest `deleteUser(id:)` or something like that. That makes the domain and functional intent of the method clear, and moves the parameter label where it belongs.
5. **Be careful with string interpolation of SQL.** In your user deletion routine, you are building the SQL statement through string interpolation of the identifier. That happens to work because the parameters are numeric, but can be problematic with string parameters. Usually we would use a prepared statement and then [bind values](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) to `?` placeholders in the SQL.
6. **Methods that `throw` should not return optionals.** Optionals are useful when writing functions that must return either `nil` or some
   value. But in this case, you always either return a value or `throw`
   errors, so use of optionals is not needed any only complicates the
   calling point. Remove the `?` in the return values of E.g.,

   ```swift
   enum DatabaseError: Error {
       case sqlError(Int32, String)
   }

   func deleteUser(by identifier: Int64) throws -> Int32 {
       let sql = "DELETE FROM user WHERE id = \(identifier)"

       guard sqlite3_exec(database, sql, nil, nil, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
           throw DatabaseError.sqlError(sqlite3_errcode(database), String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(database)))
       }

       return sqlite3_changes(database)
   }

   func findAllDepartments() throws -> [Department] {
       var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil
       let sql = "SELECT id, name FROM department"

       guard sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
           throw DatabaseError.sqlError(sqlite3_errcode(database), String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(database)))
       }

       defer {
           sqlite3_finalize(statement)
       }

       var departments: [Department] = []
       while sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW {
           departments.append(Department(id: sqlite3_column_int64(statement, 0), name: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1))))
       }

       return departments
   }
   ```
7. **Strive for highly cohesive, loosely coupled types.** In this case, you have some other code opening the SQLite database and passing the `sqlite3` pointer to the `Database` class. This is bad because it tightly couples the caller with the `Database` class, littering SQLite calls in multiple classes. It also is problematic because the `Database` type is less cohesive, not encompassing all the SQLite calls.

   If, for example, you replace SQLite with some other storage mechanism at some later date, you are going to have to not only replace your storage class, `Database`, but go through all the caller code, too.
8. **`Database` is tightly coupled with model types.** In a similar vein as my previous point, we generally want to keep model objects and database objects a little less tightly coupled than this. For example, rather than having `Department` specific methods in our base `Database` class, you would want to define a protocol for fetching and storing of data. Or, at the very least, I would move `Department` and other model-specific methods in their own extensions, to avoid cluttering the main `Database` class with model-specific methods.
9. **Consider SQLite wrapper class.** Before you write your own SQLite wrapper class, you might want to consider one of the existing ones out there. They have already wrestled with many of the basic considerations and might have interfaces to handle this.

Just a few observations.